# Как сделать чтобы рандомные числа не повторялись

Tags: java, javafx

например есть такой код который сработывает при клике

```
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
```

как сделать чтобы при нажатии если предыдущее число не совпало с настоящим, внизу написал пример

```
первый клик: получилось 5
второй клик: получилось 4
третьий клик: получилось опять 4
```

как сделать чтобы 2 раза не повторялись числа таким образом

Comment: Предопределить пул чисел заранее, по требованию извлекать с удалением случайное число из этого пула.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

            if (checkRandom(integers, random)) {
                integers.add(random);
            }
        }
        integers.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static boolean checkRandom(List<Integer> integers, int random) {
        for (Integer integer : integers) {
            if (integer == random) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Например так

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что вам не надо генерировать числа бесконечно. Тогда ответ будет таким:

1. создайте массив целых чисел нужной вам длины.
2. Заполните массив числами в порядке возрастания и убывания (начальное число и шаг прогрессии выбирите какие угодно).
3. Перемешайте массив случайным образом.
   Для получения случайных чисел просто последовательно перебирайте массив.